# SQL Server stored procedure beginner's guide

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Please recommend some websites with a quick guide. MSDN is good but it's hard to pick up some basic stuff in a short time. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the documentation has some pretty good links:

[This is a good start on MSDN for basic Stored Procedure syntax with examples.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669.aspx)

Comment: MSDN aims to be extremely thorough and complete to the point of nearsightedness.  Not necessarily good for beginners.

Answer (score 12):

here are some good ones:

[SQL Server Stored Procedures for Beginners](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/stored_procedures_basics_p1.aspx)
[SQL Server Stored Procedure Basics](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25288)
[SQL Server Stored Procedures 101](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/SQL-Server/SQL-Server-Stored-Procedures-101/) 
[Stored Procedure Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191436.aspx)

find more here:
[google: sql server stored procedure basics](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=sql+server+stored+procedure+basics&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&num=100&lr=&as_filetype=&ft=i&as_sitesearch=&as_qdr=all&as_rights=&as_occt=any&cr=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&safe=images)

Comment: The first link (http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/stored_procedures_basics_p1.aspx) is broken. I couldn't find the article using that site's search box or google, so I couldn't fix it myself.

Comment: I bet that link was working over 8 years ago when it was answered!  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[How to write a Stored procedure in Sql server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-to-write-a-Stored-procedure-in-Sql)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very helpful clip from youtube.

[Introduction to creating Basic stored procedures in SQL Server 2008](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOBDISV8cvY)

or [SQL 2008 Series: Introduction to Stored Procedures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jx63oKvU8Iw&feature=related)