# Getting error message when trying to execute code

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcommand

```
con.Open();
string qry="insert into reg1 values ('"+txtname.Text+"','"+txtaddress.Text+"','"+txtpin.Text+"','"+txtage.Text+"','"+txtgender.Text+"','"+txtcourse.Text+"','"+txtcollege.Text+"','"+txtfname.Text+"','"+txtoccup.Text+"','"+txtmname.Text+"','"+txtskills.Text+"','"+txtmobile.Text+"','"+txtemail.Text+"')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I am receiving the following error message when I try to execute this code:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Can anyone help me find the error?

Comment: Which error message do you get?

Comment: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: what is the table definition then?

Comment: please take `(column name)` as well ... or check the number of values you have taken and number of fields in db

Comment: cid int Unchecked
name varchar(20) Checked
address varchar(20) Checked
pin varchar(20) Checked
age varchar(20) Checked
gender varchar(20) Checked
course varchar(20) Checked
college varchar(20) Checked
fname varchar(20) Checked
occupation varchar(20) Checked
mname varchar(20) Checked
skills varchar(20) Checked
mobile varchar(20) Checked
email varchar(20) Checked

Comment: you need to supply value for `cid` field or make it `identity` (auto-incrementing)

Comment: @KillerR    Thanks all,i got the error rectified by a friend.for varchar(20).I had given more than 20.

Comment: In the current form, the question would be unlikely to be useful to "future generations". Voting to close.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like your column numbers in your table and your `SqlCommand` does not match. But since we didn't know anything about your table design, we never know..

If your `INSERT` command and your table doesn't have the same column number, you have to declare your column names which you want to insert these values..

I count 14 columns on your table *[from your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546345/getting-error-message-when-trying-to-execute-code#comment32537993_21546345)*, but you try to add 13 values. These are doesn't match.

But more important, you should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
con.Open();
string qry = @"insert into reg1
               values(@name, @address, @pin, @age, @gender, @course, @college, @fname
               @occup, @mname, @skills, @mobile, @email)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text);,
.....
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

you entered to much or to few values into the table in other words your table has 5 columns and you entered 6 values  or 4 check that the values you entered corresponds with your table

best advice i can give is always use a procedure it is recommended to protect against sql injection and it will reduce the chance of this happening ,it is also a lot more efficient than hard coding it from c# end

create a proc and just call it from c# end done ;)

[SQL Server stored procedure beginner's guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649938/sql-server-stored-procedure-beginners-guide)

```
     create proc example_insert
     @values varchar(100) <--- declare  parameters

     as 

     insert into [Table]([Column],[Column],[Column])
     values('','','',)<--- -this should be the same number as your columns
```

calling the stored procedure this is in vb but the principle is the same

```
        s1.Open() 'opens the connection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("example_insert", s1)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", textbox.Text)<--- a lot simpler
```

Comment: if further help is required  script your table to a query and post it